# Discord.js's `user.tag` and `user.username` in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm trying to write a Discord bot with Python for fun and according to documentation I found for discord.js (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) there should be a `user.tag` and `user.username` that gives you a string(I'm looking for a way to do this for `message.author` which is a subclass of the user). The same doesn't work in `discord.py` and I can't find anything about a similar thing for `discord.py`. Does anyone know how to do this?

code for reference:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content + " sent by " + message.author.username + message.author.tag)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    Reply = "Test"
    await message.channel.send(Reply)
```

Comment: Please read the [`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20author#discord.User) first, you may be able to find the same class under a different class name. And just a small suggestion from me, is to not regard `discord.js` and `discord.py` as the same. They may be similar, and though you may be able to find functions and or data that are the same, they're strictly different in actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the discriminator (`9999`) use `Member.discriminator`

```py
message.author.discriminator
```

Or if you're looking for whole name (`HelloWorld#9999`)

```py
message.author.name
```

Your source code

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content + " sent by " + message.author.name)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    Reply = "Test"
    await message.channel.send(Reply)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discriminator#discord.Member.discriminator)
- [`Member.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20name#discord.Member.name)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `Member.tag` I think you're looking for `Member.discriminator`

```py
tag = message.author.discriminator
```

Or if you're looking for whole name (`example#1234`)

```py
name = str(message.author) # Or `message.author.name`
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discriminator#discord.Member.discriminator)
- [`Member.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20name#discord.Member.name)

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
name = message.author.name
```

and then splice the string to get the tag, splice it by the `#`